# Gitlab CI, include rule's if condition is ignored

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've following in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
include:
  # env variables
  - local: test.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "dev"
  - local: int.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "qa"
  - local: prod.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"
```

Included files have:

```
# test.yml
variables:
  ENV: "test"

# int.yml
variables:
  ENV: "int"

# prod.yml
variables:
  ENV: "prod"
```

When the job is executed, the `rules` are ignored and all files are included, so the `$ENV` variable always resolves to `prod` no matter what value `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`  has, since the last included file was `prod.yml`. What went wrong?

Gitlab server version is 13.9

Comment: Your rule uses `CI_BUILD_REF_NAME`, which is not a predefined variable. Are you defining this somewhere? Also, not sure what the value of `ENV:` has to do with the rule.

Comment: @sytech `CI_BUILD_REF_NAME` is a predefined variable but it was deprecated by GitLab in favor of `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` in v9.0. It will be removed in GitLab v16.0. See the deprecations page https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/deprecations.html

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the variables that are part of this list - [use-variables-with-include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-variables-with-include)

CI_BUILD_REF_NAME cannot be used to evaluate rules in `include`

Comment: `CI_BUILD_REF_NAME` can be used, and that's not why OP's code is failing. 

`CI_BUILD_REF_NAME` is a predefined variable but it was deprecated by GitLab in favor of `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` in v9.0. It will be removed in GitLab v16.0, but OP is using v13.9. See the GitLab deprecations page https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/deprecations.html

Answer (score 1):

> When used in include, the CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME variable returns the full
> ref path, like refs/heads/branch-name. In include:rules, you might
> need to use if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /main/ (not == main). This
> behavior is resolved in GitLab 14.5.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-variables-with-include

The solution should be:

```
include:
  # env variables
  - local: test.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME  =~ /dev/
  - local: int.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME  =~ /qa/
  - local: prod.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME  =~ /master/
```