# Gitlab Ci include local only executes last rules

Tags: include, gitlab-ci

As per the documentation i have added the include file concept into my CI pipe line

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html

```
include:
    - local: builds.yml
        rules:
          - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"
      - local: deploys.yml
        rules:
          - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
```

but it is always taking the last final if condition. here in my case it  is always including the deploys.yml file. Appreciated any helps

here is my actual code

#.gitlab-ci.yml

```
include:
    - local: .gitlab-ci-dev.yml
      rules:
          - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"
    - local: .gitlab-ci-master.yml
      rules:
          - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
stages:
    - build
    - tests
    - deploy
before_script:
    - echo $iis_application_path
    - echo $application_pool_name
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "AjmanTaxi"
build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - dotnet restore
        - dotnet build --no-restore
        - dotnet publish .\apicicdtest\apicicdtest.csproj -c Release -o $publish_path
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - $publish_path
        expire_in: '1 hrs'
    tags:
        - windows
    only:
        - branches

deploy:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - |
            if((Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $application_pool_name).Value -ne 'Stopped'){
                 Write-Output ('Stopping Application Pool: {0}' -f $application_pool_name)
                 Stop-WebAppPool -Name $application_pool_name
                 New-Item -Path $iis_application_path -Name "app_offline.htm" -ItemType "file"
            
            }

        - Start-Sleep -s 5
        - Copy-Item ($publish_path + "*") -Destination $iis_application_path -recurse
        - |
            if((Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $application_pool_name).Value -ne 'Started'){
                Write-Output ('Starting Application Pool: {0}' -f $application_pool_name)
                if(Test-Path $iis_application_path\app_offline.htm){
                    Remove-Item -Path $iis_application_path\app_offline.htm
                }
                Start-WebAppPool -Name $application_pool_name
            }
    only:
        - branches
    tags:
        - windows
    dependencies:
        - build
```

#.gitlab-ci-dev.yml

```
variables:
    publish_path: 'bin\Release\net7.0\publish\'
    application_pool_name: 'testcicddev'
    application_name: 'testcicddev'
    iis_application_path: 'E:\temp_files\cicdtestpublishdev'
```

#.gitlab-ci-master.yml

```
variables:
    publish_path: 'bin\Release\net7.0\publish\'
    application_pool_name: 'testcicdmaster'
    application_name: 'testcicdmaster'
    iis_application_path: 'E:\temp_files\cicdtestpublishmaster'
```

here it is always taking the gitlab-ci-master.yml variables

Comment: The indentation in the code snippet you pasted is incorrect - is it correct in your actual CI file? And to clarify, the rules only work for your "main" branch, but not for "dev" branch?

Comment: @GChuf yes the indentation is proper and yes you are right the main branch only working

Comment: Does the dev branch have deploys.yml file? Can you paste the whole CI file, and the builds and deploy yaml files?

Comment: @GChuf yes indeed

Comment: And the content of all the 3 CI files? Given the information you have provuded, the config is OK and the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: i have seen one person reported the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72217633/gitlab-ci-include-rules-if-condition-is-ignored

Answer (score 2):

I do not see an `include:` in your YAML extract.
For instance, check if the issue persists with:

```yaml
include:
  - local: builds.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"
  - local: deploys.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
```

The [`rules` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) should apply only to the right '`local`' include.

---

But even if you had such a keyword, you might want to try and [*extend* those included rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends):

Something like:

```yaml
include:
  - local: builds.yml
  - local: deploys.yml

build:
  extends: .build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"

deploy:
  extends: .deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
```

The idea is  to define a `.build` job in your `builds.yml` file and a `.deploy` job in your `deploys.yml` file.
The `extends` keyword is used to inherit the configuration from the corresponding jobs in the included files.

That means you would:

1. include both `builds.yml` and `deploys.yml` files.
2. define a `build` job that extends the `.build` job from the included `builds.yml` file. This job will only run if the current branch is `dev`.
3. define a `deploy` job that extends the `.deploy` job from the included `deploys.yml` file. This job will only run if the current branch is `main`.

---

> Is there any option to define extend job name dynamically?

I don't think you can directly use an environment variable or CI/CD variable as the value for the `extends` key.

Which means you might have to create a separate job for each branch and use rules to control when they run.

```yaml
include:
  - local: config/dev.yml
  - local: config/main.yml
  - local: config/feature.yml

deploy_dev:
  extends: .deploy_dev
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"

deploy_main:
  extends: .deploy_main
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"

deploy_feature:
  extends: .deploy_feature
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^feature\//
```

For instance, with this configuration, the appropriate job will be triggered based on the branch name:

- `deploy_dev` will run for the `dev` branch
- `deploy_main` will run for the `main` branch
- `deploy_feature` will run for any branch with a name starting with `feature/`

This assumes your repository include config files like, as an example for `dev`:

```yaml
.deploy_dev:
  script:
    - echo "Deploying for dev branch"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer yes the include file is there i just skipped as it is known ..i will update the question.my ultimate objective is to make it dynamic .i have a single product and deploy it with diffrent name and locations based on the branches.i have tried all the available option but no proper solution .

Comment: is there any option to define extend job name dynamically ?

Comment: i have updated the question ..can you please check it out?

Comment: @AskarcAli I see your updated code, but did you test one of the approaches I suggested in my answer?

Comment: though that solution is not fully satisfy me i will try and let you know..appreciated your support

Comment: so where i will write the common scripts as your suggestion

Comment: @AskarcAli Do you mean the config file I mention? Those are in your repository.

Comment: No if you look at my actual code based on branch i need to deploy code in diffrent places and only when i am adding a new branch i need to update the variable location and pool information. remaining build and deployment code i should not change at all